# Python's subprocess.check_output( )

Tags: python, string, subprocess

I'm working with python's `subprocess.check_output()` and I'm using it to run a python file that takes certain attributes (like fileName, title, etc..). Everything works fine however, I decided to pass in a string variable instead of an actual string. This doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Does anyone see something that I don't?

```
import textFile
import upload
import subprocess
def upload(fileName):
    arr = []
    bunny = "big_buck_bunny.flv" #this is the variable
    arr = textFile.readLine(fileName)
    size = textFile.getLines(fileName)
    i = 0
    while(i < size):
        f = open("upload.py-oauth2.json", 'w').close()
        textFile.append("C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\tester\\upload.py-oauth2.json",arr[i])
        #This below is where i would like to pass in a variable
        subprocess.check_output('python upload.py --file="C:\\Users\\...\\anniebot\\' + bunny)
    i+=1


upload("C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\tester\\accountList.txt")
```

So I pretty much would like to change the path constantly. The problem is, I cant figure out a way to get subprocess to work without passing in a fixed string.

i would like to do something like:-

```
    subprocess.check_output('python upload.py --file="C:\\Users\\user1\\Videos\\anniebot\\" + bunny --title="title" --description="testing" --keywords="test" --category="22" --privacyStatus="public"')
```

Comment: Please post actual code not a screen shot.

Comment: use `"fixedtext\\{}\\xxxx`.format(filename)` for instance. It has nothing to do with subprocess _at all_

Comment: hey @Jean-FrançoisFabre, im not sure what you mean. could you elaborate??

Comment: hey @elethan, I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
subprocess.check_output('python upload.py --file="C:\\Users\\...\\anniebot\\' + bunny + '" --title= ...')
```

So basically concatenate the string using the **single** quote instead of the **double** quote you are using.